# React.js: Changing the child state also changes its proptype passed by parent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-proptypes

The issue I'm having is that when I change the state of the child component, the state of the parent component is also changed. I'm passing the prop to the child as so:

```
{this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
      <UserRow
        key={user.id}
        user={user}
        removeUser={this.removeUser}
        getUserInfo={this.getUserInfo}
        finishFunc={this.finishChanges}
      />
    ))}
```

And then assigning that prop to the a state of the child like this:

```
state = {rowUser: this.props.user};
```

However, when I update this child state, it seems that the parent state updates without re-rendering.

I'm displaying the information through the prop, not the state

```
<div>{this.props.user.rules.length !== 0 ? this.props.user.rules.length : null}</div>
```

You can see the initial display [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc0tG.png)

When I click on the "Add" or "Remove" buttons, the state **and** display changes. You can see the change in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RditX.png)

I'm confused on how changing the child's state updates the parent's state without me specifically passing the data back to the parent. I also don't see how it is changing the display since I'm using the prop, not the state.

You can see all of my code in a [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjxnp8879). You can see the permissions number change whenever you click the "add new permission" and "remove permission" buttons, which I don't want to happen.

How can I avoid having the parent state automatically change when I change the child state?

Comment: user is an object, I'm assuming from 'this.props.user.rules....' Since you are passing a reference to an object, updating it anywhere will affect any component that uses it. Of course, I can't see how your parent is using it from the snippets of code you posted, so I have to guess.

Comment: I have a sandbox with all of the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjxnp8879, as stated above.

Comment: yeah, I think I am right. https://codesandbox.io/s/l398p1qrv9

I made sure to copy the permissions array into the new state. Now, since the props.user.permissions array and the state's permissions array are no longer the same reference, adding a permissions does not update anything

Comment: @DevinFields This is what I'm looking for in terms of the parent not being affected by the child. However, it seems that I can't add or remove permissions within the UserRow component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

The issue lied in how I was changing the child's state `state = {rowUser: this.props.user}`. I was mutating the data and resetting the state like this:

```
addPermission = () => {
  const tempUser = { ...this.state.rowUser };
  tempUser.permissions.push({
    property: "select permission",
    info: "type info..."
  });
  this.setState({ rowUser: tempUser });
  console.log("[UserEditingRow.js] permission added");
};
```

**The Solution:**

Changing the data directly (i.e. `tempUser.permissions.push({...});`) was causing a problem. I used React [immutability helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) to help update the child's state more specifically. So, the new function would be:

```
addPermission = () => {
  this.setState(
    update(this.state, {
      rowUser: {
        permissions: {
          $push: [{property: 'select rule', info: ''}],
        },
      },
    }),
  );
  console.log('[UserEditingRow.js] rule added');
};
```

Setting the state with immutability helper allowed the child component's state to change without updating the parent component's state and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your Sandbox, the issue is you are assigning `props.user` to `state.rowUser` and is creating a pointer to the parent components value. This means whenever you change `this.state.rowUser` it will actually be updating the reference to `props.user`.

**Solution**

1. Use the `constructor()` to bind the `props.user` to `state.rowUser`, this is the recommend approach, additionally use the spread operator to create a new instance of the object passed into the component, this will ensure no pointer is created.

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
constructor(props){
  this.state = { rowUser: ...props.user }
}
```

**Additionally**

Looking quickly at the sandbox I also found a few other anti-patterns that will be causing you some issues.

1. You are updating state directly `Line 76 to 84 in UserRow` then calling setState, what you should be doing is using the spread operator to clone the object `const tempUserRow = { ...this.state.userRow }` then manipulating the object and set it in state via `setState`. This will ensure your shallow compare in `shouldComponentUpdate` passes and re-renders your component.
2. You are using `shouldComponentUpdate` which is good, but your not doing anything that `React.PureComponent` does for you out of the box, so you should change `extends React.Component` to be `extends React.PureComponent`

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for your reply. I've made the above changes to the sandbox: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjxnp8879), but the parent's state is still getting changed. I also had to change the syntax for `...props.user` as it was giving me an unexpected character error.

Comment: This has me stumped! I will keep looking over the sandbox but can't work out how the parent component is being modified resulting in a reload of the component .

Comment: I believe I answered that question in my comment on the question. Working from Max's answer, you just need to clone the permissions object. The rest syntax may clone the outer-most object, but if there is a shared reference within that outer shell, I don't believe it is cloned.